# Python: Error in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

See, I started learning Python today and I am stuck in a situation.
I was solving a very simple question and I completed it but there is a problem.

First of all, let me tell the question and the constraints. Here is the question:

Given an integer,`n`, perform the following conditional actions:

1. If `n` is `odd`, print `Weird`.
2. If `n` is `even` and in the inclusive range of `2 to 5`, print `Not Weird`
3. If `n` is `even` and in the inclusive range of `6 to 20`, print `Weird`
4. If `n` is `even` and greater than `20`, print `Not Weird`

Here is my code:

```
n = input("")
if n%2!=0 :
    print ("Weird")
elif n%2==0 :
    for n in range(3,4,5) :
            print ("Not Weird")
elif n%2==0 :
    for n in range(6,21) :
            print ("Weird")
else :
    if (n%2==0 & n>20) :
        print ("Not Weird")
```

I compiled the code, everything is fine but for the input `18` and `20` I must get `Weird` as output but I am getting `Not Weird`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean binary `&`, or do you mean logical `and`?

Comment: I mean a logical and like we do in `C` or `C++` for example,

`if(x>4 && x%2==0)`

Comment: In that case it should be `and`, which would be `&&` in C.  `&` is a binary operator with the same meaning as in C.  Before you ask, in Python it is `or`, not `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you asked specifically to use for loops? If not you can try this!

```
n = int(input(""))

if n%2==1:
    print("Weird")
elif n%2==0 and n in range(3, 6):
    print("Not Weird")
elif n%2==0 and n in range(6, 21):
    print("Weird")
elif n%2==0 and n>20:
    print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much!! but why was it not working with `for` loop?

Comment: You can omit the `n % 2 == 0 and ` from the beginning of every `elif` case; you'll only reach them if the `n % 2 == 1` test fails, so it's redundant to recheck evenness when you already guaranteed "not oddness". Also, particularly in Python 2, but still true in Python 3, it's better/faster to do (for example) `elif 6 <= n <= 20:` rather than `elif n in range(6, 21):`; `6 <= n <= 20` doesn't need to create an object at all (and on Py2, the object created is a moderate size `list` which must be scanned element by element, where `6 <= n <= 20` is 1-2 cheap logic tests).

Comment: @dev_rituraj your range was set up incorrectly, what you have in your first elif statement range(3,4,5) would not work. You were basically saying range between 3 and 4 with steps of five. Remember its range(start,stop,step). Also your "Weird" would have printed each time the  loop iterated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elif with same condition it shouldn't. 
 Change it or remove one elif

```
n = input("")
if n%2!=0 :
    print ("Weird")
elif n%2==0 :
    if n>20:
        print ("Not Weird")
    for n in range(3,4,5) :  #range shouldn't be like this. But for your understanding i leave it as it is
            print ("Not Weird")
    for n in range(6,21) :
            print ("Weird")
```

Final else also not needed

Comment: Please read the conditions and tell me what should I do if I remove one `elif`

Comment: It will come in to second elif since  both are same. So merge 2 and 3 together

Comment: oh, yes! wait I'll try this

Comment: Nope, it worsens the situation. By doing so it shows error for other inputs also. for example, 24

Answer (score 0):

Your have a problem with range(3,4,5).  list(range(3,4,5)) is [3]..probably not what you expected...range is start, stop, step.

You could do for n in [3,4,5] or range(3,6)

Comment: I think the problem is in the 2nd `elif` statement, because the input `18` and `20` lies in the `range(6,21)`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you keep re-defining `n` in your `for` loops, thus at each conditional statement after the first `for` loop your `n` is not what was initially given.

In your two cases of `n=18` and `n=20`, the first condition `n%2!=0` is False, so then the second condition is tested. `n%2==0` is `True`, so the `for n in range(3,4,5):` loop is executed.  The first (and only) iteration of that loop sets `n` to 3 and prints 'Not Weird'.  Since `n` is now `3`, none of the remaining conditions in you code are `True`, so they do not execute.

The following would be much simpler given your requirements:

```
def isweird(n):
    if n%2 or n in range(6,21):
        return 'Weird'
    if n in range(2,6) or n > 20:
        return 'Not Weird'

for n in range(23):
    print(n, isweird(n))
```

Output:

```
0 None
1 Weird
2 Not Weird
3 Weird
4 Not Weird
5 Weird
6 Weird
7 Weird
8 Weird
9 Weird
10 Weird
11 Weird
12 Weird
13 Weird
14 Weird
15 Weird
16 Weird
17 Weird
18 Weird
19 Weird
20 Weird
21 Weird
22 Not Weird
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the code you've provided.

The most obvious is that you have the same condition repeated in two branches of an if...else chain. The second such condition,

```
elif n%2==0:
    for n in range(6,21) :
```

will never execute.

Also, the use of for loops in those branches is incorrect. Those should be conditionals. You use a loop when you want to repeat an action, but here you have one variable and you want to ask a question about it. That's an "if":

```
elif n%2==0 :
    if n in range(3,4,5) :
            print ("Not Weird")
```

But that leads to the next bug, which is the use of `range`. As written, you're specifying the range of numbers starting with 3, running up to 4 (not inclusive), in steps of 5. That would be the range containing 3.
To specify the inclusive range from 2 to 6, you would write

```
elif n%2==0 :
    if n in range(2,7):
            print ("Not Weird")
```

Ranges are inclusive on the bottom end and exclusive on the top end. This seems counterintuitive at first, but it's generally what you want when working with zero-indexes. For example, you would like range (10) to have 10 members, and to start with zero, hence contain all of the base-ten digits.
You can also write this as

```
elif n%2==0 :
    if 2 <= n <= 6:
            print ("Not Weird")
```

which would be my preference.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's walk through your code line by line and see what's happening in the case of an input of 18:

```
 if n%2!=0 :
     print ("Weird")
```

18 modulus 2 is equal to 0, so this print statement will not be reached.

Next:

```
 elif n%2==0 :
     for n in range(3,4,5) :
         print ("Not Weird")
```

Hello, this one matches!  Therefore, the `for` statement will be executed.  *No other statements in your if / elif / else chain will be reached for the value 18, because you found a match here.*

**However**, you're not going to see what you expect, because the `for` statement does not do what you think it does.  You're thinking that it's going to look at `n` and for a value of `n` that's found in the the list [3,4,5], the value `Not Weird` will be printed.

That's not what `for` does.  Instead, `n` will be *changed* to one each of the values in the range, in turn, and the code inside the loop will be executed with `n` set to that value.  Now, you're wondering why, if this is the case, you don't see the `Not Weird` printed three times?  The reason is that `range` is a function and it doesn't return a list of the supplied numbers, it returns a bunch of numbers starting with (in your example) 3, and ending with 4, but taking only every 5th number.  By coincidence, this gives a `range` with only 1 value (the value 3) which is why `Not Weird`appears only once.

Here is a corrected and annotated version of your code:

```
if n%2 != 0:
    print ("Weird")
else: 
    #Don't need elif, there are only two cases odd, or not.
    #But, inside this branch we have three possibilities.
    if n in [2, 3, 4, 5]:
        #I just enumerate here, instead of using range.  You forgot about 2, BTW
        print ("Not Weird")
    elif n in range(6,21)
        # Note the use of if (or elif), not for.
        print ("Weird")
    else:
        print ("Not Weird")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 n = int(input())
if n % 2 != 0:
    print('Weird')
elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(2, 6):
    print('Not Weird')

elif n % 2 == 0 and n in range(5, 21):
    print('Weird')

elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    print('Not Weird')
```

This will work....the key point there is inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

```py
n = int(input().strip())
check = {True: "Not Weird", False: "Weird"}

print(check[
        n % 2 == 0 and (
            n in range(2, 6) or 
            n > 20)
    ])
```

This will be the shortest solution without using if else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct solution:

```
n = int(input())
if n%2==0 and n not in range(6,21):
    print("Not Weird")
else:
    print("Weird")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = input()
n = int(num)

if n%2 !=0:
    print('Weird')
if n%2==0 and n in range(2,6):
    print('Not Weird')
if n%2==0 and n in range(6,21):
    print('Weird')
if n%2==0 and n>20:
    print('Not Weird')
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for everyone to understand the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this: 
            n= int(input("")
            if n%2==1:
              print("Weird")
           elif n%2==0 and n in range(3, 6):
             print("Not Weird")
          elif n%2==0 and n in range(6, 21):
            print("Weird")
         elif n%2==0 and n>21:
           print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: What does your answer add to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
n=3
if(n%2!=0):
  print("Weird")
else:
    if(n>=2 and n<=5):
      print("Not Weird")
    elif(n>=6 and n<=20):
      print("Weird")
    elif(n>20):
      print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post with some explanation